# __attribute__ ((weak)) overriding existing function

Tags: c, gcc, glibc, libc

I'm trying out some of the solutions to [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42310814/6850771).

Say I'm running on a system that implements `itoa`. I have this code:

```
char *my_itoa (int a, char *b, int c)
{
    return itoa(a, b, c);
}

char* __attribute__ ((weak)) itoa(int a, char* b, int c)
{
     strcpy(b, "No itoa");
}
```

If I call `my_itoa(10, str, 10)` with the above code, `puts(str)` gives me "No itoa".

However, if I simply write:

```
char *my_itoa (int a, char *b, int c)
{
    return itoa(a, b, c);
}
```

and call `my_itoa(10, str, 10)`, `puts(str)` gives me "10".

My understanding was that `__attribute__ ((weak))` would implement a function if it was not already implemented. Is that its true behavior? What's going on here?

Comment: Weak symbols are supported for ELF targets, and also for a.out targets when using the GNU assembler and linker. Are all those things true (ELF, GNU assembler and linker)?

Comment: @DougCurrie I'm using MinGW, so GNU but not ELF.